# How to re-use the result of a subquery in the main query, with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Here is a crude example of the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
SELECT
    (array_agg(ts))[1] as ts,
    (array_agg(ticker))[1] as ticker,
    round(avg(m1)::decimal,  (SELECT price_tick_size FROM exchange_debug.instruments WHERE ticker = 'BTCUSDT')) as m1,
    round(avg(m5)::decimal,  (SELECT price_tick_size FROM exchange_debug.instruments WHERE ticker = 'BTCUSDT')) as m5,
    round(avg(m15)::decimal, (SELECT price_tick_size FROM exchange_debug.instruments WHERE ticker = 'BTCUSDT')) as m15,
    round(avg(m30)::decimal, (SELECT price_tick_size FROM exchange_debug.instruments WHERE ticker = 'BTCUSDT')) as m30,
    ...
```

I need to know the rounding value for the data, load it once and reuse it everywhere.

I thought about using 'USING' above the query to get the rounding value:

```
WITH tick_size AS
    (SELECT price_tick_size FROM exchange_debug.instruments WHERE ticker = 'BTCUSDT')
SELECT
    (array_agg(ts))[1] as ts,
    (array_agg(ticker))[1] as ticker,
    round(avg(m1)::decimal, tick_size.price_tick_size),
    round(avg(m5)::decimal, tick_size.price_tick_size),
    ...
```

But then I get the following error:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "tick_size"

So, I can do this:

```
round(avg(m1)::decimal, (SELECT price_tick_size FROM tick_size)) as m1,
```

But I can't help to think there has to be something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the subquery in the `FROM` clause of your main query, as long as it is guaranteed to return exactly a single row:

```
SELECT
    (array_agg(ts))[1] as ts,
    (array_agg(ticker))[1] as ticker,
    round(avg(m1)::decimal, tick_size.price_tick_size),
    round(avg(m5)::decimal, tick_size.price_tick_size),
    ...
FROM
    ...,
    (SELECT price_tick_size FROM exchange_debug.instruments WHERE ticker = 'BTCUSDT') AS tick_size
```